# GORM or block with 3 conditions

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

How to specify or block in GORM createCriteria with 3 conditions. in or block, if we specify like the below,

```
Domain.createCriteria.list(params){
or{
   collection1{
      //conditions for collection 1
   }
   collection2{
     //conditions for collection 2
   }
   collection3{
    //conditions for collection 3
  }
 }
}
```

EDIT:

This type of or condition is worked for me when i am using or condition with properties of **same** domain class. But when i am using collections (one to many) in or block, this is not worked.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?  If it failed, what was the error message?

Comment: There is no error message, the results are not correct and some results are skipped. Instead of adding the data in 3rd condition, it reducing the data by other two conditions.

Comment: I think you have to pass the right values, take your time and check everything one or more time

Comment: The code displays the data, which is Common in all blocks.

Comment: I think inside the block it is 'AND' logic

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it is working like charm.

```
try {
        def criteria = App.createCriteria();
        def app = criteria.list {
            /*eq("id",1 as long)*/
            or {
                // org is collection
                org {
                    eq("id",1 as long)
                }
               //usr is collection
                usr {
                    eq("id",1 as long)
                }
            }
        }
        println(app)
    }
```

have you tried anything by your own is the question

Comment: @user2463026 yes from your comment, my suggestion is check your db values